# Looking for reference on gauge fields as connections. 

Tags: reference-request, gauge-theory, dg.differential-geometry, quantum-field-theory

Can anyone give me references where I would see a detailed exposition of how to translate gauge field theory as known to physicists into the language of connections.  I am looking for a detailed exposition on the mathematical formulation of Yang-Mills field theory. Something which might also give an exposition about Chern-Simons theory and the related whole bag of what get called "topological actions"

I had read a nice long discussion on the geometrical formulation of gauge field theory in a post  at Terence Tao's blog namely [this article](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/what-is-a-gauge/%20)  and also probably something on Secret Blogging Seminar (but I can't locate that link)

Along similar lines I had seen a very old book by Atiyah and Hitchin on this.

I would like to know what books/expository papers on this are read by graduate students today when they try entering this field?

Also advanced references on the topic would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Geometry, Topology, and Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068)* by Nakahara

*[Classical Theory of Gauge Fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691059276)* by Rubakov

*[Modern Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961623)*, Part 2 by Dubrovin, Fomenko, and Novikov

Answer (score 9):

The books that I liked by far the most are the two volumes on [Topology, Geometry and Gauge Field](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387949461)s by Gregory Naber. It has a very nice introductory chapter which tells you why one should care about connection and then starts topology from the scratch. The second book ends with a short introduction to Seiberg-Witten gauge theory (to be found on [his homepage](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~gln22/), "Introduction to Donaldson and Seiberg-Witten Theories").

I also enjoyed John Morgan's lectures on Gauge theory in the book "Gauge theory and topology of four-manifolds".

Comment: I second the suggestion of Naber's book. Physicist friends of mine have found it very helpful in passing between physical language and mathematical language. 

Comment: I had read through Naber's volume 1 during my undergrad and had found it exciting and insightful. 

Haven't seen the volume 2.  Given your recommendation I think I should take a look then. 

Comment: Can you also provide a link to the home-page from where you said that the book is available? 

I did quite a few Google searches but nothing came up except the flipkart and amazon and google books link for the book. 



Comment: Sorry for the unclarity: Not the book is available on his homepage, only the appendix to Seiberg-Witten Gauge theory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

But your link doesn't work. Can you kindly correct it? 





Comment: Sorry, again. The link directly to the pdf does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found K. Moriyasu's *An Elementary Primer for Gauge Theory* a helpful expository introduction.